# Insert the right data from API to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a working script which automatically sends the data to my MongoDB every second.
I currently stuck with a problem of how I can send the exact data from API to MongoDB.

**FULL CODE**

```
    var requestPromise = require('request-promise');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * * *', function() {
    var burl = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCUSDT";

    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ourRequest.open('GET', burl, true);
    ourRequest.onload = function() {
        var x1 = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText)
        var btcdata = (x1.volume)
        console.log(btcdata);
        saveToDatabase(btcdata);
    }
    ourRequest.send();
});

const saveToDatabase = function(BTC) {

    const url = 'mongodb+srv://Hexynator:test123@cluster0-1kunr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        const dbo = db.db('Crypto');
        const myobj = { Name: 'BTC', Volume: 'Volume' };
        dbo.collection('Crypto-Values').insertOne(myobj, (error, res) => {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log('1 document inserted');
            db.close();
        });
    });
};
```

The problem as I think in this line of code here:

```
const myobj = { Name: 'BTC', Volume: 'Volume' };
```

This is how it looks in MongoDB collection
[image: MongoDB Collection]

I also tried to do this -         `const myobj = { Name: 'BTC', Volume: btcdata };`
I receive this error - `ReferenceError: btcdata is not defined`

Question: How I can change `'Volume'` to be a number which I receive from API here - `console.log(btcdata);`

Goal: To be BTC as the name in database and Volume be a number from API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const saveToDatabase = function(BTCdata) {
    const url = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-1kunr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        const dbo = db.db('Crypto');
        const myobj = { Name: 'BTC', Volume: BTCdata };
        dbo.collection('Crypto-Values').insertOne(myobj, (error, res) => {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log('1 document inserted');
            db.close();
        });
    });
};
```

previously you where not using the data (BTCdata) you send to the function .